# Argument inside Observable.Create method

Tags: angular, observable

```
 ....
var observable = Observable.create(source  => {
      console.log(source);
      source.next(Math.random());
    });
```

Could someone explain to me why am I getting the following?

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: null, syncErrorValue: null, …}
```

for `source`? It is supposed to be an **Observer** isn't it?

```
interface Observer<T> {
  closed?: boolean;
  next: (value: T) => void;
  error: (err: any) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observer is just an interface, Subscriber is its implementation.

From the docs of Subscriber class:

> Implements the Observer interface and extends the Subscription class. While the Observer is the public API for consuming the values of an Observable, all Observers get converted to a Subscriber, in order to provide Subscription-like capabilities such as unsubscribe. Subscriber is a common type in RxJS, and crucial for implementing operators, but it is rarely used as a public API.

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html